# Does "cervus" mean "deer" or "wild goat" (in Psalmi 104:18)?

Tags: vulgata

In Vulgate, in Psalmi 104:18, it says:

> Montes excelsi **cervis**,
> petra refugium herinaciis.

I thought *cervus* meant *deer*, but the New International Version translates this verse as:

> The high mountains belong to the **wild goats**,
> the crags are a refuge for the hyrax.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *New International Version* gives the translation for the Hebrew יָעֵל (yael), which means *[mountain goat](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3277.htm)*.

Concerning the Vulgate's translation, John Gill notes in his *[Exposition of the Entire Bible](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/psalms/104-18.htm)*:

> The Septuagint, Vulgate Latin, and Arabic versions, render it "for the
> harts", or deer; and so Apollinarius: but the word is not used of
> them.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by this: did the Septuagint translators just get it wrong? Regarding the Vulgate, it's important to note that the current version of the Psalms is (essentially) a literal translation from the Septuagint. Jerome didn't do a *de novo* translation from the Hebrew until later, but that version was never much used. I noticed that the 1945 psaltery changes *cervis* to *ibicibus*.

Comment: @brianpck: Sure looks like it. But would αίγαγρος have been known to the Jewish community in Egypt?

Comment: @Joshua What Jewish community in Egypt?

Comment: @FlatAssembler: According to https://www.thoughtco.com/the-story-of-the-septuagint-bible-119834 , the Septuagint was translated in Alexandria, which is in Egypt.